# Django rest filter data by field

Tags: django-rest-framework

Controller:

```
class TicketMessageSerializerView(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = TicketMessage.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TicketMessageSerializer
```

How to filter the list of messages by the ticket_id field, the value of which is taken from the url:

```
path('api/tickets/<int:ticket_id>/messages/',
      views.TicketMessageSerializerView.as_view()),
```

Comment: In the DRF, you can easily take an object by pk.
But I did not find the functionality that I need ...

Comment: Can you please share your `TicketMessage` model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case you work with a `ListAPIView` (since you return a *list* of objects), and you can override the `get_queryset` method to specify what `TicketMessage`s that should be returned, so:

```
class TicketMessageSerializerView(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = TicketMessage.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TicketMessageSerializer

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().get_queryset(*args, **kwargs).filter(
            ticket_id=self.kwargs['ticket_id']
        )
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked for me.
I tried using ListAPIView, but with get function (facepalm)